# Calling stores procedures with table value parameter in Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, table-valued-parameters

I have created below stored procedure in MS SQL 2014.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[LanguageList] AS TABLE
(
  LanguageID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StudentLanguageInsert]
(
    @stuId INT,
    @langList AS [dbo].[LanguageList] READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert into [dbo].[StudentLanguage]([StudentId],[LanguageId])
    SELECT @stuId,LanguageID FROM @langList; 
END
GO
```

I am executing this like below:

```
DECLARE @lang_List LanguageList;

INSERT INTO @lang_List(LanguageId)
VALUES (1), (2), (3);
EXECUTE [dbo].[StudentLanguageInsert]
      @stuId = 5,@langList = @lang_List;
```

It is working fine in SQL server. 
But When I imported this in EDMX file, it is visible like this:

```
public virtual int StudentLanguageInsert(Nullable<int> docId)
        {
            var docIdParameter = docId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("docId", docId) :
                new ObjectParameter("docId", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("StudentLanguageInsert", docIdParameter);
        }
```

There are no parameters to pass table-valued parameter to this function.
Here I do not know, how can I pass table-valued parameters to this procedure.

Comment: Why -1 without any comments. At least mention issues with questions rather than down voting.

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this. Don't worry, not all downvotes are relevant